# Radio button hide and show issue

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to change the content by selecting the different radio button. My codes seem not working. Any problem with it? Here is the [FIDDLE](http://fiddle.jshell.net/GodRevenge/6mp86q38/):

**HTML**

```
   <div id="category-table" style="display: block;">
            <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons" style="float:right;">
                <label class="btn btn-show-category active">
                    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off" value="A-categories" checked=""> A Categories
                </label>

                <label class="btn btn-show-category">
                     <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off" value="B-categories"> B Categories
                </label>
        </div>         

        <br><br>
            <div class="all-categories">
                <div class="content-header">Category A</span></div>
            </div>

            <div class="used-categories" style="display:none;">
                <div class="content-header">Category B</span></div>
            </div>

    </div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[type="radio"]').click(function () {
        if ($(this).attr("value") == "A-categories") {
            $(".used-categories").hide();
            $(".all-categories").show();
        }
        if ($(this).attr("value") == "B-categories") {
            $(".all-categories").hide();
            $(".used-categories").show();
        }
    });
});
```

Any Suggestion?

Comment: You aren't including jQuery in your fiddle.. see [this updated example](http://fiddle.jshell.net/xnhh93p6/). You could also swap the `click` event listener out for a `change` event listener.

Comment: @Josh Crozier, omg I didnt realise it. Thanks dude! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Just check fiddle. It looks like you did not include jquery js file.

Answer (score 1):

make the click event to change event in radio button.

I have update the fiddle check it out
[Here is the updated fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/6mp86q38/2/)